# Iptables not blocking subnet?

Tags: linux, iptables, fail2ban

Fail2ban on my email server just banned the following offensive address:

```
REJECT     all  --  *      *       185.211.245.198      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

However I already had the following rules active in the fail2ban chain:

```
REJECT     all  --  *      *       185.211.0.0/16       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Below is the output of the iptables -vnL (for chains INPUT and f2b-zimbra-smtp only):

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 66463 packets, 11M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 150K   54M f2b-zimbra-smtp  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25,465
 149K   54M f2b-zimbra-smtp  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25,465
 149K   54M f2b-zimbra-smtp  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25,465
6600K 7170M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 483K  696M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 2403  132K ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
50273 2076K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25
  495 21612 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
61597 2470K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
44944 1799K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:465
45134 1815K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:587
45193 1812K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:993
44853 1796K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:995

Chain f2b-zimbra-smtp (3 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    7   420 REJECT     all  --  *      *       185.211.245.198      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
...
   15   900 REJECT     all  --  *      *       185.211.0.0/16       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

So obviously the rule for the 185.211.0.0/16 subnet didn't work.  Could someone explains why?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you say "obviously the rule for the 185.211.0.0/16 subnet didn't work". Obviously it _did_ work, otherwise there wouldn't be any packets in the counter.

Comment: I meant, if it had worked then it had blocked traffic from 185.211.245.198, not allowing several attemps and then add a new rule for it?